# Dynamic SQL - inserting into #temp table by executing a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having an issue that's very slightly differently from others that have already been answered here.

I have a Stored Procedure that has 1 parameter and is returning different results (number of columns) based on that parameter. In this Stored Procedure, I create a table called #FreightData. The end of that Stored Procedure has something like the following:

```
IF @IncludeIDs = 0 
BEGIN 
    select [Buyer], [Contract], [Product], [Shipowner], [DespatchOrder] from  #FreightData
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    select * from #FreightData
END
```

All of the above is working successfully.

Then, in another Stored Procedure called [FreightProfile], I'm trying to populate a #temp table with the results from:

```
EXEC [dbo].[EXCEL_FreightData] @IncludeIDs = 1
```

I've used the exact same CREATE TABLE definition that is in [EXCEL_FreightData] (with a different table name - #FreightProfile_results) and am trying to populated the new temp table using

```
INSERT INTO #FreightProfile_results
EXEC [dbo].[EXCEL_FreightData] @IncludeIDs = 1
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I'm trying a solution now using OPENROWSET, so that I don't have to provide the table definition, to get around this issue, but if anyone had any suggestions on the above, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to execute procedure to check if column list are correct.

Comment: Generally you would avoid producing inconsistent signatures from a stored procuedre. It might be better to make this a table valued function, of which you can use a select statement. Then your inner TVF always does the same thing and you put your fancy include/exclude logic in the outside wrapper SP only (rather than in two seperate places, which is liable to introduce bugs and maintenance overhead)

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

I had copied the following in the table definition, hence the problem.

```
[ID] [int] identity (1,1) Not Null
```